# Maximum number of tuples in this relation R , ER model?

Tags: entity-relationship, rdbms, erd

[image: ER DIAGRAM]

Answer given is : `1000`

I don't understand which side it's many-one relation and which side it's one-one relation.

Comment: What do the lines mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ER diagramming conventions, and you haven't explained or given a reference to yours. This includes conventions for expressing cardinalities, and in particular cardinalities for n-ary relationships with n > 2.

Googling the text of the question: This diagram appears in a (different) question in [this solution](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dbclass/ics184/assignments/fall2001/midterm_sol_final.doc) which says of the diagram:

> (i) for a unique pair (a,b) there can only be an unique value of c in the relationship set R, and
>   (ii) for a unique pair (a,c) there can only be an unique value of b in R.

So it seems that an arrow indicates that the target entity appears just once for *a given appearance of a combination of the others* in the relationship set.

> A has 100 entities, B has 1000 entities, and C has 10 entities

There's at most one C per (A,B) pair; so every (A,B) pair is unique in the set. So there are at most 100*1000=10000 entities.

There's at most one B per (A,C) pair; so every (A,C) pair is unique in the set. So there are at most 100*10=1000 entities.

From both those, we know there are at most 1000 entities.

There actually could be 1000 entities, since each possible (A,C) pair (of which there are 1000) could appear in the set each with a different B (of which there are 10000) without violating the cardinality constraints. So the maximum number of entities is not smaller than 1000.

So the maximum number of associative entity triples in the relationship set is 1000.

> I don't understand which side it's many-one relation and which side it's one-one relation.

Notice that there aren't really "sides" to an n-ary relationship for n > 2. There are sides to each binary relationship between an entity type participating in a role and (n-1)-tuples combined from entitity types participating in the other roles. (We could report a cardinality for each side of each role's binary relationship. Although maybe the link's method just gives the participants per (n-1)-tuple, and not the (n-1)-tuples per participant.)

Comment: how did you satisfy the relationship of many to one in A and B entity , since you directly took all possible combinations of A and B , we even need to satisfy the relationship between the two right .

Comment: I just fixed a typo that had B & C entity counts switched. Your comment is not clear so I don't know whether the typo had anything to do with your comment. What do you mean, "the relationship of many to one in A and B entity"? Do you mean the (A,B) vs C binary relationship? What do you mean "satisfy" that relationship? Do you mean satisfy its cardinality constraint? What is "satisfy the relationship between the two right"? Does right = correctly? I would agree that the table *can't* hold every AB pair since there's more than 1000. I meant to say that the table could contain all 1000 AC pairs.

Comment: A has 50 entities , B has 20 entities , relationship between A and B is many to one , Now when we combine AB as single entity ,my query is how can we do 50*20 ? Since it is many to one so any entity in A can be mapped with atmost one entity in set B , so how can we say that maximum number of A,B pairs is 50*20 ?

Comment: Read the quote in the answer & the rest of the answer & my comment. The diagram gives no info re a relationship on A & B. (You mean the projection on them?) It says each (A,C) has 1 B & each (A,B) has 1 C; this doesn't imply anything re A vs B. So by default it says many:many. It also doesn't give cardinalities in the other direction, ie how many (A,C)s can appear with a given B or (A,B) with a C. ER diagrams give *some* cardinality-oriented constraints re relationships, details per the method. They don't give all constraints. Or all cardinality constraints we can imagine on projections.

Comment: The example in your comment is *different* from the example in the question. So why are you mentioning it? Nevertheless: In your example the maximum cardinality is 50, because each A has 1 B so there can be at most 50 As in the table. That is *the same reasoning* that says there can be at at most 1000 (A, C)s in the table given at most one B per (A,C) & 1000 (A,C) values to possibly participate (since there are 100 A values & 10 C values available to possibly participate).

Comment: But in your explanation , you wrote .                                  There's at most one C per (A,B) pair; so every (A,B) pair is unique in the set. So there are at most 100*1000=10000 entities. , Now when there is many to one relationship between A and B , and one entity in A can be associated with Atmost 1 entity in B , so how can we say that there are atmost 100*1000 entities overall (AB Pairs) in general .       Sorry but I am not getting this , that why are we doing multiplication here when one entity in A can be associated with Atmost one entity in B .

Comment: Yet again: *There is no relationship on A & B here* except the derivable one "for some C, R relates A, B & C" (whose associated table is the projection of R's on A & B) and we have been told nothing explicitly about it. In particular its cardinality. And we can infer nothing about it so it's many:many. Why do you keep talking about a "many to one relationship between A and B" when you don't say what relationship you mean & anyway *there is no such cardinality constraint here*?

Comment: PS I said there are at most 10000 tuples. And *also* at most 1000 tuples. And therefore the maximum number of tuples is at most 1000. And that it was at least 1000. And so it is 1000. Do you want me to say "there are not more than 10000 tuples" instead of "there are at most 10000 tuples"? But what does this have to do with a constrained relationship on A & B? It is not so that "one entity in A can be associated with at most one entity in B". Again: *Why* do you think that? (If you are ever talking about (A,C) or (A,B) tuples please don't ever call them "A".) Please answer my questions.

Comment: PS Read my answer. The arrows are *not* giving cardinalities for binary relations (presumably you mean projections of R) (A,B) & (A,C). They are giving info on binary relations ((A,C), B) & ((A, B), C). And they are not saying they are many:1. They are only saying a (A,C) value has one B & a (A,B) value has one C. And the third line to A has nothing to do with the arrows, it says a (B,C) subtuple can have many As.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation , I have just last confusion as we said there could be atmost one C per AB pair and atmost one B per AC pair , why can't we have atmost one BC per A means why can't we hold A->BC here .

Comment: We can. "So it seems that an arrow indicates that the target entity appears just once for *a given appearance of a combination of the others* in the relationship set". Such a diagram cannot say anything directly re A->BC. The entity counts (100/1000/10) are not 1 or 0 so they don't force any FDs to hold or not hold. Then Armstrong's axioms say that A->BC can hold or not hold; both are consistent with the diagram. Or just find example table values. Read the manual re the diagrams you are supposed to use. PS "At most 1" is odd--say "1". There has to be *at least* 1 "for *a given appearance*".

Comment: Yes got it , actually I thought that if I assume cardinality constraint  from A to B as many to one ,  from A to C as many to one and from B to C as one to one so I was under impression that if we combine AB as a pair and say that we have atmost one C per AB Pair then after combining AB as one pair , do we still satisfy the constraint between A and B which was earlier taken to be many to one ?

Comment: I was trying to do aggregation between any of  the two entities first and then the aggregated entity would be in relationship with the 3rd entity but I couldn't find my answer using this approach . This is where I was struck . That while constructing the triple <ABC> in one table , do we individually also satisfy the cardinality constraints between two entities ,as they were mentioned in the original ques , here I assumed from A to B as many to one and from A to C as many to one ,from B to C as one to one .

Comment: Hi. I can't make much sense of your last two comments. Please post a question if you have one. It seems like mostly your writing doesn't: reflect what you read; or ask about the first thing you didn't understand; or answer questions to help us find your misconceptions; or justify the things you claim & give your assumptions to help us find your misconceptions; or use enough words, sentences & descriptions to be clear. So all I can do is essentially guess & repeat myself & ask questions, which I don't normally do because it is ineffective. So please *do* the things in that list when writing.